# SQL QUERY to get city name begining with a vowel NO OUTPUT o

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like

select city from station where city like '[aeiou]%';

this should return all the city names starting with vowels but it doesnt.Please esplain the regeion and suggest other methods

Comment: It's not regex. mentioning character class is of no use. Rather it will try to look for `[` character first.

Comment: try this one:

SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE  city RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'

Answer (score 1):

Since everey station should have a city

```
select city from station where LOWER(SUBSTR(city,1,1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

should be good, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select city from station where city RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]'
```

I think your expression may be failing because you didn't specify the start of the string with '^'.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `regex` in your query (Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98fe39/1)):

```
SELECT * FROM station WHERE city RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]'
```

Without specifying the `$` at the end of the regex expression we are basically saying return every row where the city `starts` with a vowel.

The `$` sign means the end of the string we are matching. Just leave it out if you don't have additional requirements.

You don't need the `%` either.